# Editing Publishing Separation Pattern

Tags: nodes

I am new to drupal and let me say I am very impressed with the ecosystem around it, however I am struggling to work out how I can implement the [Editing Publishing Separation Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EditingPublishingSeparation.html) correctly where I can publish content to an entirely different instance of Drupal.  This instance will have identical code but will only have live content.  Any one who has experience with Sitecore the master and web databases is effectively what I am after.

One thought I had was to use RSS feeds or some sort of custom push to create content on the remote instance.

Any insight would be much appreciated

Thanks

Aaron

Comment: Are you set on separating them for performance reasons or something else?  If it's just content control maybe have a look at [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation)?

Comment: Hey Darvanen, My main motivation is to have content editing centralised on a server within our corporate network where it can use LDAP for user authentication, this information is not available to a server in the wild. I also see it as an opportunity to tune the different environments for for their different responsibilities. Enabling varnish for example on the  CD server. Other than that I might just be stuck in a Sitecore way of thinking that could be obsolete in a Drupal world, that being said I do respect what Martin Fowler suggests, and tent to try to at least explore making them work.